# Eclipse: enable automatic build / compile for each Java source edition

Tags: eclipse

How to enable automatic build & compile 'for each Java source edition'? Not just 'Build Automatically.'

For example, after a random code edition 'before saving' it, errors are shown in the 'Problems' view. In the following figure, Eclipse does not automatically compile.

[image]

And in the figure below, Eclipse does automatically compile after typical some codes 'before saving all'.

[image]

How to achieve the Eclipse functionality of the second image? In other words, after typing some codes in Java source, the errors are shown 'before' saving all. I accidentally disabled this and do not know how to re-enable it.

---

Don't know which one in Errors/ Warnings to configure after trying many. I solved this problem only by creating a new Eclipse folder (by decompressing the downloaded eclipse .zip) and import just a few old preferences like 'Keys Preferences' and 'Code Style Preferences' and reset most 'Preferences' manually. But there's probably some setting responsible for this functionality. I searched online with some keywords related to automatic build but failed to find the answer, and checking 'Build automatically' is not the answer. The question is to look for the right configuration in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/ Warnings and change the settings as per your preference.